# How to get n stars on 5 stars here

Tags: reactjs, rating

This is the function I'm getting the stars for rating. I need 5 white stars and get the n golden on it.

```
let n = []
for(var i = 0; i < product.avg_rating; i++) {
  n.push(<i class="fa fa-star" key={i}></i>)
}
```

[image]

I'm calling this variable here

```
<div className="rating">
  {n}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more complete code, see [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and a more clear explanation of what isn't working as desired and what your expected result should be? There is very little information here, and no debugging details.

Comment: What and where are the white stars? What is rendering the UI for the screencap? A single for-loop and a line of JSX isn't enough. Please update question with complete code and provide enough details so others can see what and where things may have gone awry.

Comment: okk, I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Rating` component that takes a rating prop value and conditionally colors a star. You can do this in a single pass.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faStar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

// create [1,2,3,4,5] once
const starArray = [...Array(5).keys()].map(i => i + 1);

const Rating = ({ rating }) =>
  starArray.map(i => ( // use many times
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      key={i}
      icon={faStar}
      color={rating >= i ? "orange" : "lightgrey"}
    />
  ));
```

[image]

I used `react-fontawesome`, but logic is conceptually identical, just swap in whatever iconography you are using.

[image: Edit rating display]

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question
You can do something like this:

```
let golden = [];
for(var i = 0; i < product.avg_rating; i++) {
  golden.push(<i class="fa fa-star" key={i}></i>)
}
let white = [];
for(var i = 0; i < (5-product.avg_rating); i++) {
  white.push(<i class="fa fa-star" key={i}></i>) // provide appropriate class for white stars
}

return(
<div className="rating">
{golden}
{white.map((i)=><span> {i} </span>)}
</div>
)
```

Comment: somehow its working but showing no golden stars...subtracted values come as a box stars